# when enter key is pressed the data must go to DB where txtbox is inside gridview

Tags: gridview

I have a gridview in which there is 5 textboxes . When, I press enter the data present in the textbox must go to database. Where I'm using row_command for inserting data to db and the TextBox is in itemtemplate mode of GridView.
How can I Insert it? Please give me a suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridview's row command to insert the values in DB,
For that take another template field and take a button to insert the data,and give that button a command as AddNew.

```
CommandName="AddNew"
```

refer this sample code i made for you

```
 protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if(e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
{
TextBox txtUsrname = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrusrname");
TextBox txtCity = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrcity");
TextBox txtDesgnation = (TextBox) gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrDesignation");
TextBox txtState = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrstate");
TextBox txtCountry = (TextBox) gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrcountry");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd =
new SqlCommand(
"insert into Employee_Details(UserName,City,Designation,State,Country) values('" + txtUsrname.Text + "','" +
txtCity.Text + "','" + txtDesgnation.Text  +
txtState.Text + "','" + txtCountry.Text "')", con);
int result= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```